# puppetlabs/firewall - "Could not find resource type 'firewall'"

Tags: puppet

I'm fairly new to puppet, so this might just be me not seeing the obvious.

I want to use the puppetlabs-firewall module and wrote a small module of my own. The init.pp looks like this:

```
class cmmfirewall {
  resources { 'firewall':
    purge => true,
  }
  Firewall {
    before  => Class['cmmfirewall::postv4', 'cmmfirewall::postv6'],
    require => Class['cmmfirewall::prev4', 'cmmfirewall::prev6'],
  }
  class { ['cmmfirewall::prev4', 'cmmfirewall::postv4']: }
  class { ['cmmfirewall::prev6', 'cmmfirewall::postv6']: }
}
```

When I apply this class to a node I get the following message:

`err: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter name failed on Resources[firewall]: Could not find resource type 'firewall' at /etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules/cmmfirewall/manifests/init.pp:42`

My puppet.conf on the agent looks like this:

```
# File managed by Puppet

[main]
    vardir = /var/lib/puppet
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    modulepath = /etc/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules
    user  = puppet
    group = puppet
    archive_files = true
    archive_file_server = handsoff.dc0.mynetwork.de

[agent]
    certname = test3.dc0.mynetwork.de
    server = handsoff.dc0.mynetwork.de
    report = true
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
    graph = true
    pluginsync = true
    runinterval = 300
```

So as you can see, pluginsync should be activated, but both of the folders in the modulepath `/etc/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules`are empty. So my guess would be the problem is somewhere there and pluginsync isn't working as i expect it to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction on where to look for the error, please?

Comment: Have you installed the module from puppet forge? puppet module install puppetlabs-firewall

Comment: Does the module appear when you do `puppet module list`?

Comment: You mean an the agent or on the master? On the agent, that list is empty, but I'm using other modules there and they work fine. On the master it also doesn't show up, but I'm using environments here. This module is in testing, whereas the master himself is in 'production'.

Comment: The module must be available in the `$modulepath` for the `$environment` that your agent chooses. The agent must have `pluginsync` enabled so that the type/provider code is downloaded to its `$vardir`. Once the code has been synced to the agent, it should work for all environments.

Comment: So, that might be the problem. In my puppet.conf on the agent there are those 2 module paths: `/etc/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules`, both are empty. But pluginsync is set to true. - I attached the puppet conf to my main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually the moment I copied the puppetlabs-firewall module to my common folder (which gets includes in both environments, testing and production) it worked.

Now I just really would like to now why. Here is the puppetmaster config file. Maybe someone can tell my why it behaves the way it does.

```
### File managed with puppet ###
## Module:           'puppet'

[main]
    # The Puppet log directory.
    # The default value is '$vardir/log'.
    logdir = /var/log/puppet

    # Where Puppet PID files are kept.
    # The default value is '$vardir/run'.
    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    # Where SSL certificates are kept.
    # The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl

    # Allow services in the 'puppet' group to access key (Foreman + proxy)
    privatekeydir = $ssldir/private_keys { group = service }
    hostprivkey = $privatekeydir/$certname.pem { mode = 640 }

    # Puppet 3.0.x requires this in both [main] and [master] - harmless on agents
    autosign       = $confdir/autosign.conf { mode = 664 }

    show_diff     = false

### Next part of the file is managed by a different template ###
## Module:           'puppet'

[agent]
    # The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
    # associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
    # the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
    # option.
    # The default value is '$statedir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    # Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
    # extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
    # The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig

    # Disable the default schedules as they cause continual skipped
    # resources to be displayed in Foreman - only for Puppet >= 3.4
    default_schedules = false

    report        = true
    pluginsync    = true
    masterport    = 8140
    environment   = production
    certname      = handsoff.dc0.mynetwork.de
    server        = handsoff.dc0.mynetwork.de
    listen        = false
    splay         = false
    runinterval   = 300
    noop          = false
    configtimeout = 120

### Next part of the file is managed by a different template ###
## Module:           'puppet'

[master]
    autosign       = $confdir/autosign.conf { mode = 664 }
    reports        = foreman
    external_nodes = /etc/puppet/node.rb
    node_terminus  = exec
    ca             = true
    ssldir         = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
    certname       = handsoff.dc0.mynetwork.de
    strict_variables = false

[production]
    modulepath     = /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppet/environments/common:/usr/share/puppet/modules
    config_version = 
[testing]
    modulepath     = /etc/puppet/environments/testing/modules:/etc/puppet/environments/common:/usr/share/puppet/modules
    config_version =
```